# @RestResource(exported = false) not work on findById function of kotlin based spring mvc project

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-rest

I have the following **kotlin** repository:

```kotlin
@RepositoryRestResource
interface ChapterRepository: CrudRepository<Chapter, Long> {
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    override fun findAll(): MutableIterable<Chapter>
    
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    override fun findById(id: Long): Optional<Chapter>
}
```

With the `@RestResource` annotation above, the `findAll` is not exposed, but the `findById` is still exposed. That means I can not access `/api/chapters` url but `/api/chapters/<id>` is still accessible.

Below is project info:

- Spring Boot version: 2.3.2
- Kotlin version: 1.3.72
- JDK version: OpenJDK 11.0.6

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.  After some debugging I've noticed that the data rest code searches for the corresponding "findById" method on the RestRepository, and due to a "java.lang.Long" vs "kotlin.Long" type issue, is unable to find your overriden "findById" method, and therefore the `@RestResource(exported = false)` is not picked up. This class from data rest `DefaultCrudMethods` tries to find the "findById" method.