# Spring Data Rest - repository.findById not used for item resource GET

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-rest

I need to set some permissions on method level for my API. For this I'm adding  `@PreAuthorize` to the methods in my repository. It works for `findAll` but not for `findById`. It seems that the method is not used at all for the route `/api/repo/1`

To test my instinct, I've provided a default implementation for the `findBy` method that always returns null and indeed, it does not seem to work however I'm not sure if the generated implementation respects my default implementation or simple overwrites it...

Here is my repository:

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository: CrudRepository<MyEntity,Long>{
  
  // 1.
  override fun findById(id: Long): Optional<MyEntity> {
     return Optional.ofNullable(null)
  }
  
  // I swapped these two, did not leave both of them in the class at the same time...
  
  // 2.
  @PreAuthorize("isAdmin()")
  override fun findById(id: Long): Optional<MyEntity>

  @PreAuthorize("isAdmin()")
  override fun findAll(): MutableIterable<MyEntity>
}
```

`isAdmin()` is a custom method made by me but the same happens with the built in `hasAuthority`

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63086888/restresourceexported-false-not-work-on-findbyid-function-of-kotlin-based-sp) question that had a comment pointing out that the issue is that Spring is looking for a method with a parameter of type `java.lang.Long` not `kotlin.Long`. In theory one can use `java.lang.Long` in Kotlin but it should be avoided at all times so the simplest solution I could find was to switch my repositories to Java which is not that big of a deal since these are only interfaces.